# How to create object in object Spring JPA (Jhipster)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

I am beginner using java and spring jpa (expecially Jhipster). I want to create object in object like this :

[image]

But I always get like this :

[image]

property buildingsDTO always empty, this is my code, please correct my code in order I get like first picture.

location.java (Domain)

```
public class Location implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "content_location", nullable = false)
private String content_location;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "location")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Building> buildings = new HashSet<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent_location() {
    return content_location;
}

public Location content_location(String content_location) {
    this.content_location = content_location;
    return this;
}

public void setContent_location(String content_location) {
    this.content_location = content_location;
}

public Set<Building> getBuildings() {
    return buildings;
}

public Location buildings(Set<Building> buildings) {
    this.buildings = buildings;
    return this;
}

public Location addBuilding(Building building) {
    this.buildings.add(building);
    building.setLocation(this);
    return this;
}

public Location removeBuilding(Building building) {
    this.buildings.remove(building);
    building.setLocation(null);
    return this;
}

public void setBuildings(Set<Building> buildings) {
    this.buildings = buildings;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Location location = (Location) o;
    if (location.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), location.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Location{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", content_location='" + getContent_location() + "'" +
        "}";
}}
```

locationDTO.java

```
public class LocationDTO implements Serializable {

private Long id;

@NotNull
private String content_location;

private Set<BuildingDTO> buildings = new HashSet<>();

public Set<BuildingDTO> getBuildingsDTO() {
    return buildings;
}

public void setBuildingsDTO(Set<BuildingDTO> buildings) {
    this.buildings = buildings;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent_location() {
    return content_location;
}

public void setContent_location(String content_location) {
    this.content_location = content_location;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    LocationDTO locationDTO = (LocationDTO) o;
    if(locationDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), locationDTO.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LocationDTO{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", content_location='" + getContent_location() + "'" +
        "}";
}}
```

locationMapper.java

```
public interface LocationMapper extends EntityMapper <LocationDTO, Location> {

@Mapping(target = "buildings", ignore = true)
Location toEntity(LocationDTO locationDTO); 
default Location fromId(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setId(id);
    return location;
}}
```

buildingDTO.java

```
public class BuildingDTO implements Serializable {

private Long id;

@NotNull
private String content_building;

private Long locationId;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent_building() {
    return content_building;
}

public void setContent_building(String content_building) {
    this.content_building = content_building;
}

public Long getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}

public void setLocationId(Long locationId) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    BuildingDTO buildingDTO = (BuildingDTO) o;
    if(buildingDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), buildingDTO.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BuildingDTO{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", content_building='" + getContent_building() + "'" +
        "}";
}}
```

please anyone help me.
thanks.

Comment: Don't post code as links to images. Post code as code. Then post the **relevant** code: the one hat has a bug.

Comment: Where is your `BuildingsDTO` class ?

Comment: I have just sent BuildingDTO class. @sunkuet02

Comment: Would you please also add your controller class ?

Comment: I don't know where is the controller, I generate this apps using Jhipster, maybe you know what is the name of controller, I'm so sorry, I'm beginner so I don't know much about Spring JPA (expeacilly Jhipster). @sunkuet02

Answer (score 0):

By default jHipster will mark any OneToMany entity relationships as @JsonIgnore so that the Set of buildings is not returned in the JSON:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "location")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Building> buildings = new HashSet<>();
```

If you want this to show up in the JSON then you should remove that annotation and also mark it with an eager loading strategy so that the set of buildings are loaded as you expect:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Building> buildings = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I ave tried your suggestion, but still empty property buildingsDTO. Maybe, do you have anysuggestion. .?

Comment: @andrewMK No.. beyond that I think it should work. Although I have to say I am confused as to why you would expect a field called buildingsDTO in your JSON. There is no field called buildingDTO anywhere. If you want to avoid confusion I would avoid using DTOs. You can select this as an option when you generate your entities through jHipster.